# Ouputting the results of os.popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to send the results of os.popen() to an output file.  Here is the code I have been trying

```
import os

cmd = 'dir'
fp = os.popen(cmd)
print(fp.read())  --Prints the results to the screen
res = fp.read()

fob = open('popen_output.txt','w')
fob.write(res)
fob.close()

fp.close()
```

The output file is just blank.  The results of the command are however displayed on screen.  I have also tried using Popen like this (as per the subprocess management documentation):

```
import subprocess

fob = Popen('dir',stdout='popen_output.txt',shell=true).stdout
```

As well as:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('dir',stdout='popen_output.txt,shell=true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a file object to stdout not a the file name as a string, you can also use `check_call` in place of Popen which will raise a `CalledProcessError` for a non-zero exit status:

```
with open('popen_output.txt',"w") as f:
      subprocess.check_call('dir',stdout=f)
```

If you are on windows `subprocess.check_call('dir',stdout=f, shell=True)`, you could also redirect using `>` using shell=True:

```
subprocess.check_call('dir > popen_output.txt',shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  This got it going.  Thanks for the help!

```
fob = open('popen_output.txt','a')
subprocess.Popen('dir',stdout=fob,shell=True)
fob.close()
```

Comment: You should accept an answer instead of posting your working code. You should understand the elements of Padraic's answer some more.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more what you'd like to do. You can process then write to file.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for line in process.stdout:
    #processing then write line to file...
    file.write(line)
```

If you don't want to process, then you could just do it in your `subprocess` call.

```
subprocess.run('dir > popen_output.txt', shell=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling fp.read() twice instead of saving the results of a single fp.read() call as res, printing res, and writing the res to the output file. A file handle is stateful, so if you call read on it twice, the current position after the first call will be at the end of the file/stream, hence your blank file.

Try this (just providing the relevant changes):

```
fp = os.popen(cmd)
res = fp.read()
print(res)
```